# Assembly reference issue . 

Tags: c#, projects-and-solutions

I am getting this error when trying to build a winforms solution:

*The located assemblys manifest destination does not match the assemblys reference.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you will find this article useful: http://blogs.msdn.com/junfeng/archive/2004/03/25/95826.aspx.

Typically this indicates that the assembly found during execution / build time is not the one that has been added to your project.

Answer (score 0):

Check to see you're using the right version/build of your assembly.

I found two different references to this - hope it helps! ( [one](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Community/Forums/tabid/795/forumid/108/threadid/279257/scope/posts/Default.aspx) | [two](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-sdk/1183/app-use-newer-versions-of-a-DLL) )